# Saving sucessfully copied Files from A to B in Java when Programm crashes?

Tags: java

i have to copy lots of files from A to B in Java, problem is that the Programm might crash.
Already sucessfully copied Files cannot be copied again, when the programm restarts. How can I save in a textFile already copied Files?

My solution below is not 100% sucessfull, sometimes it doesnt save all the successfully copied files.
I wonder if theres a better approach to this issue.Thanks a lot in advance.

```
 package com.mycompany;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class CopyingData {
    
    public static void saveFilesAlreadyCopied(ArrayList<String> filesToSave, String fileName) {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String file : filesToSave) {
            pw.println(file);
        }
            
        pw.close();
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Variables:
        File sourceDir = new File("sourceDir");
        File destinationDir = new File("destDir");
        ArrayList<String> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> filesAlreadyCopied = new ArrayList<>();
        
        //Create dirs:
        sourceDir.mkdirs();
        destinationDir.mkdirs();
        
        //Generate 1000 Files for Testing:
        for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++) {
            File textFile = new File("sourceDir/textfile"+i+".txt");
            try {
                textFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listOfFiles.add(textFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
        
        //Copy files from sourceDir to destinationDir:
        for(String file : listOfFiles) {
            Path sourcePath = Paths.get(file);
            Path destPath = Paths.get(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + new File(file).getName());
            try {
                Files.copy(sourcePath, destPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                filesAlreadyCopied.add(file);
                saveFilesAlreadyCopied(filesAlreadyCopied,sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +"backupCopiedFiles.txt");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }               
        
    }

}
```

Comment: I find it strange that instead of fixing whatever is causing your program to crash, you're instead updating your file moving code.

Comment: There's no reason you can't retry the copy if it fails (add a loop checking for success).  Otherwise, your current code is writing out all previously written files to the log for each file - you should only need to write the just-written file to the log (keep the write stream around for this).

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.Its not my programm that is crashing, but the system from my company that it have this ocurrence. So my boss told me to develop a programm that copies files from A to B, but that is prepared for crashes in the system also.

Comment: Side question: is there a reason this has to be done _in Java_, as opposed to executing a console command?  All major OSs have some form of `rsync`/`robocopy` or directory-copy command, which would mean you just need to issue the relevant command (after picking the relevant flags).  Otherwise, what's the point of the copy?  You can obviously read those files, so why not just read them from that location?

Comment: Im not sure, but I guess Boss wants some java tool to deliver files to different locations and be monitoring directories for incoming files. Problem is, no file can be lost or copied more than once. I thought, some last modified comparison on files already copied in B from A might do the trick. But B doenst keep this files neither, so they arent available for comparison.

Comment: Can a Java Programm in a Linux Shell safeguard that all handled Files are beeing copied without losing some if the System where its running might crash?

Comment: You cannot fix a crasing computer with Java. You need to fix the root cause.

Comment: @jurez the "root cause" could simply be a file system is full. The fix is to free up or add space, and afterwards you don't want to restart the file copy. (This is an extremely common scenario for applications that move data, usually called some type of "checkpoint".)

Comment: @michael Then why do it with Java? rsync is a perfect tool for this.

Comment: @jurez This stripped down example, I assume, isn't the entire application. It's fine to address the possibility of an [XY problrem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and propose alt solutions; but no harm in answering the actual question, either. If your company can use GPLv3 rsync code, sure, I'd re-use rsync.  But patching together disparate tools creates a whole new set of problems, esp. when leaving the JVM. But there are Java implementations of rsync as well, where relevant code could be (re-)used, again if the corp allowed it (but also not trivial).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible problem you might have is running out of disk space, and I can see how after copying millions of files, terabytes of data, & then crashing on the last file, you would want to just free up some disk space & continue with the last file.

But consider this: the algorithm as written is basically as follows (assuming a checkpoint file "chkpt" contains list of files successfully copied):

1. for each file `f`,
2. copy file `f`,
3. update checkpoint file `chkpt`

So, if step #2 fails to write to the file system, then you can resume based on the contents of `chkpt`. But what happens if step #3 fails to write to the file system? (Do you create a checkpoint file for the checkpoint file?) The odds of this happening increase with the size of `chkpt`, which you currently have as containing the entire list of files to copy (could be a problem for a large list of files).

I might recommend the following (as food for thought) to decrease the odds of being unable to recover:

1. if you want to persist a list of files to copy, then create that first on disk, just once; e.g., `filelist.txt`, containing `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, etc
2. before starting the copy, create a file called e.g. `copying` containing the "next file to copy", e.g., if you've already copied files `file1.txt` through `file31.txt`, it would contain `file32.txt`
3. start to copy the file (eg `file32.txt`)
4. if the copy fails, and the program crashes, the existence of a file called `copying` indicates where things stopped -- restart copy of `file32.txt`
5. if the copy succeeded, do a "move" (file rename) of `copying` to `completed` (so, file `completed` would contain filename `file32.txt` ...also, obviously, call these files whatever you want). A file move/rename won't usually fail, nor should it become corrupted as often as writing a large file.
6. continue with the next file: create a new file `copying` with the next filename in the list (don't modify the file list)

Does that make sense? (Thoughts?) The level of effort above what you currently have isn't much more, but it might reduce the chance of running into an "unrecoverable" state (i.e., corrupted checkpoint file)..

Comment: thanks a lot, this is something that might work well within my whole implementation of my Programm. Im using Apache Commons IO Monitoring Classes,and this makes it posible to resfresh this list file. For this issue ill have to make this other lists to be sure, after a crash and restart, the right files will be copied.

Answer (score 0):

I have made  some changes to your code, to handle fail scenarios, please try below code and make happy your boss:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class CopyingData {

    public static void saveFilesAlreadyCopied(ArrayList<String> filesToSave, String fileName) {
        PrintWriter pw = null;
        try {
            pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (String file : filesToSave) {
            pw.println(file);
        }

        pw.close();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String operationFolder = "C:/Downloads/code_play-folder/";
        //Variables:
        File sourceDir = new File(operationFolder+"sourceDir");
        File destinationDir = new File(operationFolder+"destDir");
        String progressFilePath = operationFolder+"sourceDir" +File.separator + "backupCopiedFiles.txt";
        File progressReportFile = new File(progressFilePath);
        ArrayList<String> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> filesAlreadyCopied = new ArrayList<>();
        if (progressReportFile.exists()){
            filesAlreadyCopied.addAll(Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(progressFilePath)).stream().filter(data-> !data.trim().equals("")).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        }



        //Create dirs:
        sourceDir.mkdirs();
        destinationDir.mkdirs();

        //Generate 1000 Files for Testing:
        for(int i = 0;i<1000;i++) {
            String fileName = operationFolder+"sourceDir/textfile" + i + ".txt";
            File textFile = new File(fileName);
            try {
                if (!textFile.exists()) {
                    textFile.createNewFile();
                    Files.write(
                            Paths.get(fileName),
                            ("contentToAppend"+fileName).getBytes(),
                            StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listOfFiles.add(textFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        listOfFiles.removeAll(filesAlreadyCopied);
        //Copy files from sourceDir to destinationDir:
        for(String file : listOfFiles) {
            Path sourcePath = Paths.get(file);
            Path destPath = Paths.get(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + new File(file).getName());
            try {
                Files.copy(sourcePath, destPath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                filesAlreadyCopied.add(file);
                saveFilesAlreadyCopied(filesAlreadyCopied,sourceDir.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator +"backupCopiedFiles.txt");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this implementation, very well implemented